# How to expose port of kubernetes from docker desktop

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I am using the local Kubernetes cluster from Docker Desktop on Windows 10. No virtual machines, no minikubes.

I've deployed my application in one namespace (i.e. local-app) and the application(i.e. on port 9000) is deployed successfully running inside a pod.
If I port-forward the pod and hit "localhost:9000" it works.

But I don't want to port-forward. So to do that I've added ingress-Nginx(controller) But it is not working

How can I skip port-forwarding? Any example or approach would help.

Comment: While deploying the application I've given the hostname name as "app.local" and the scheme is http://

Comment: For ingress to work you also need `ingress` and `service` resources did you add them too?

Comment: Yes I've added them too